# Grails Spring Security Ldap without manager

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

How can I use the user's credentials for binding to the domain, without having a manager user/pass.

I know that it's possible in Spring Security LDAP, but how can I do it with Grails?

Here's how to do it in java: http://turgaykivrak.wordpress.com/2009/03/26/spring-security-authenticate-user-on-ldap-without-manageradmin-user/

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could work is by using

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.anonymousReadOnly = true //must be allowed on your AD server
```